# How to connect Docker containers in series?

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose

**Question:** Is there a tool to create series of Docker containers?

**My use case**

In a nutshell:

- idea: enrich CSV data and transform to RDF
- two main steps:

  - enrichment of CSV
  - transformation CSV to RDF

I would like to put each main step into its own Docker container with defined input and output. Later more container should be attachable.

**Docker-Compose doesn't seemed to fit**

As far as i know, **docker-compose** helps you creating a *bundle* of Docker containers, which basically starts all containers together. But it doesn't let you first start container 1, after it's finished it starts container 2 and so on.

In the following a illustration:

`Input => [Container 1] ==> ... ==> [Container n] ==> Output`

*Input* means something like a volume or file. *Output* may be a generated file in a volume. Container shouldn't run in parallel, because they depend on each others input/output.

**Use shell scripts**

My current demo implements the upper approach using plain bash scripts. I first start container 1, let it finish the enrichment and after it stops, i start container 2 for the transformation.

**I was wondering, if there is a more elegant approach or tool available?**

Comment: Maybe spin up Jenkins in Docker to orchestrate the tasks for you.

Comment: while docker is cool, what you describe sounds like a unix pipe line. Why create multiple virtual machines when 2 programs, connected by a pipe and redirecting output to file would do? i.e. `csvEnrichment arg1 ... argN | csv2rdf [arg1 .... argN] > /path/to/outfile.rdf` ? Good luck.

Comment: @shellter: The mentioned use case represents the current situation, but i plan to add further containers later on. My approach is to avoid running programs (which sure would be a way!), but i want to deploy this "infrastructure" later on different systems which run different OS/system configurations.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing I'm aware of currently that allows for **sequential** instantiation of containers. I'm still falling back to using scripting for it, but you may be able to accomplish something more generic using the Remote API. Would involve significantly more work, however.